# Calculating the field that is not presented in constructor

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I have a class with 3 fields: A, B, and C. I can create an instance of this class in two ways: pass all fields to the constructor, or pass only A and other properties will be calculated based on A.

```
class MyClass {
    val A: String
    val B: String
    val C: String

    constructor(A: String, B: String, C: String) {
        this.A = A
        this.B = B
        this.C = C
    }

    constructor(A: String) {
        this.A = A
        val (_B, _C) = Calculator.calculate(A)
        this.B = _B
        this.C = _C
    }
}
```

This approach uses two secondary constructors without primary one. But from my point of view, it looks pretty heavy. Is it possible to rewrite this logic in a more elegant way?

Comment: what does `calculate` return? as it is destructurable, may the same type be OK in `MyClass` itself?

Comment: It returns `Pair<String, String>`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something as follows might be ok for you. You may want to replace `Pair` with an actual type then instead...

```
class MyClass(
        val A: String,
        val BC : Pair<String, String>
) {
    constructor(A: String, B: String, C: String) : this(A, B to C) // is this then even needed?
    constructor(A : String) : this(A, Calculator.calculate(A))
}
```

Or alternatively if it makes more sense to have the three separate properties, the other way around, which was also shown by [k0enf0rNL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56005942/6202869) :

```
class MyClass(
     val A: String,
     val B: String,
     val C: String
) {
  constructor(A: String) : this(A, Calculator.calculate(A))
  constructor(A: String, BC : Pair<String, String>) : this(A, BC.first, BC.second)
}
```

Finally, if you do not want to expose some of the constructors, feel free to mark them `private`, e.g. the following will expose the same as your shown example:

```
class MyClass(
     val A: String,
     val B: String,
     val C: String
) {
  constructor(A: String) : this(A, Calculator.calculate(A))
  private constructor(A: String, BC : Pair<String, String>) : this(A, BC.first, BC.second)
}
```

Maybe you rather need something to pass a function instead (as you also used `Calculator.calculate(A)`). Then you may want to add the following as a constructor:

```
constructor(A : String, func: (String) -> Pair<String, String> = Calculator::calculate) : this(A, func(A))
```

If this is rather what you wanted from the beginning, then even a class such as the following might be something for you:

```
class MyClass(val A: String,
              func: (String) -> Pair<String, String> = Calculator::calculate) {
    val B: String
    val C: String

    init {
        func(A).also { (newB, newC) ->
            B = newB
            C = newC
        }
    }
}
```

If you then just want to pass `A`, `B` and `C` without an actual calculation (or passed function), you can still do it as follows (basically discarding the passed `A`):

```
MyClass("myA") { /* _ -> */ /* A -> */
   "myCalculatedB" to "C"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My personal favourite is to abuse companion object invoke operator:

```
class MyClass(val A: String, val B: String, val C: String) {

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(A: String): MyClass {
            val (B, C) = Calculator.calculate(A)
            return MyClass(A, B, C)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I only dislike the word "abuse" here ;-) what I like on that variant is, that you can easily move such functions outside the class using extension functions on the `Companion`, which therefore also easily allows adding additional variants...

Comment: I would even use a direct assignment for the invoke... it doesn't do that much, so you can still easily grasp it, e.g.: `operator fun invoke(A: String) = Calculator.calculate(A).let { (B, C) -> MyClass(A, B, C) }`  (new lines where appropriate)

Comment: @Roland I though of it, even already edited my answer but discarded. In the general case there could be more than just one external calculation, and things could get ugly with `.let` version.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it as a data class and at least get rid of the default constructor like so

```
data class MyClass(
    val A: String,
    val B: String,
    val C: String
) {
    constructor(A: String, calculated: Pair<String, String> = calculate()) : this(
        A,
        calculated.first,
        calculated.second
    )
}

fun calculate() : Pair<String, String> = "this" to "that"
```

Comment: My mistake, I messed up the constructor implementation. Fixed it now.

Comment: regarding your comment in the answer: I don't think so... but you can still add an additional constructor for that, e.g.: `constructor(A: String, BC : Pair<String, String>) : this(A, BC.first, BC.second)`

Comment: Whether it's a data class isn't really relevant here.